# need to login to wordpress when someone logs into my site

Tags: wordpress, cakephp

I have a site thats made in cakephp and then i have a wordpress blog thats in a subdirectory /news. When someone registers with my site it automatically creates an account with the same login credential for the wordpress site aswell. So is there a way so that when someone logs into my site it also logs them into the wordpress site aswell?

I think wordpress uses cookies or session authentication so could I just set the necessary session or cookie variables up? and what would they be if i did?

Thanks

Comment: There's an interested related forum discussion: http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Wordpress-and-cakephp-td1313751.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! What I did was download an ajax login plugin for wordpress and looked at the ajax call that it made when I used it using the firebug net tab. Then all I had to do was replicate that ajax call when someone logs into my site!